# .Net Core 3.1 web api application responds late, what should I do?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I rented hosting for my React and webapi application, it has the following features.

2048 GB RAM, 2 CORE CPU, Windows plesk

webapi is running in subdomain, react app is running in domain.
When the request goes from front-end to back-end, my response time reaches 30 seconds. It's not true that it takes that long, I don't know what to do.

I came across this error in the logs, what should I do?

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
      Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[59]
      Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {bbed084d-b792-4390-9522-4577fdbd1449} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:21700
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: D:\vhosts\mydomainmydomain.com\api.mydomainmydomain.com
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

When I examine the log records, there are only 2 lines that change.

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {fc1810c2-3dca-4644-ba55-b8b977a8c8cd} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:6281
```

The key value and port number are different for all logs. Could this be the reason for the slowdown?

**Startup.cs**

```
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowOrigin",
            builder => builder.WithOrigins(new string[] { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8000", "http://localhost:3001", "http://localhost" }).AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader().AllowCredentials());
    });

    var tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOptions").Get<Core.Utilities.Security.Jwt.TokenOptions>();

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(opts =>
    {
        opts.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        opts.Password.RequiredLength = 5;
        opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;


    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddAuthentication(opts =>
    {
        opts.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        opts.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.SaveToken = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKeyHelper.CreateSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey),
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
    });

    services.AddDependencyResolvers(new ICoreModule[]
    {
        new CoreModule()
    });

    services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
        opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
    }).AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Comment: The warnings are not relevant to slow response times. You should add more logging (and turn log level to debug) to find out more. Also, change the log formatting to add timestamps.

Comment: @SebastianRedl how can I turn log level ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0